# Can static class functions of a templated class be used without a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class which contains a static function which does not depend on the template parameter. Yet the compiler seems to force me to specify a typename when I use the function.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    ...
    static void function();
};

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::function() {
    ....
}
```

This function can be used as:

```
MyClass<int>::function();
```

But the 'int' is just there to satisfy the compiler. It doesn't mean anything, and can be replaced by any other type, which doesn't increase code readability. I would like to do someting like

```
MyClass<>::function();
```

or even

```
MyClass::function();
```

but the compiler doesn't let me. I realize that this is because in the header files I have explicitly marked the function as being templated, but when I remove the '< T >' from the header file it doesn't compile either.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If the type over which the template is being instantiated doesn't affect the function, I'd wonder whether it should really be a member function (even static) at all. Perhaps it should really be a external function in the same namespace? (Don't misunderstand: I'm not saying the current design *is* wrong, only that I'd think twice about whether it might be).

Comment: @Jerry - I can't think of a case in which this design would NOT be wrong.  Maybe being external is not the right response, it could be in a base, but clearly using the template system where it's not needed is bad.  Can you think of any reason why this would be warranted?

Comment: You should definitely consider making it a non-member function. If you're not convinced, take a look at this article by Scott Meyers, "[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197)".

Comment: @CrazyEddie: No, I can't think of a reason -- I just hesitate to condemn it outright without knowing more about what's going on.

Comment: If it is not related to T and thus not related to MyClass<T> and takes no parameters that are related to T, then it seems it should not be a member of the class. Maybe a free standing function is more appropriate.

Comment: `template<typename A, typename B> class A{ /*friend function createA*/};` then `template<typename T> auto createA(const T &t) { return A<typename T::Type1, typename T::Type2>{}; }`. This give the easiness of not specify template parameters in `createA` function. Unfortunately static function must be outside template class, so it is organizing mess and namespace pollution. No other problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you had this:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    static void boom()
    {
        static int n = 0;
        std::cout << ++n << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now imagine what happens if you say `Foo<int>::boom(); Foo<int>::boom();`, and compare that to the not-at-all equivalent `Foo<int>::boom(); Foo<char>::boom();`.

Comment: I think this best answers my question. So, basically, I have the choice between adding a meaningless type (and leave readers of my code puzzled) or remove the function from the class by placing it in the contextless pool of global functions. Or are there other options which make it clear that function() _conceptually_ belongs to MyClass?

Comment: @marcelnijman: I think a common namespace would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 8):

The type is very important!

Templates can be *specialized*, and therefore:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    static void function() { std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; }
};


template <>
class MyClass<City> {
public:
    static void function() { launchRockets(); }
};
```

is a viable program.

If you then write `MyClass::function()`, should it annihilate Bagdad or print a friendly message ?

---

Of course, if there is no reason for this function to do anything else that printing, then it should perhaps be a function *on its own*:

```
void function() { std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; }
```

which is invoked simply by `function()`, hey, it's even shorter as there is no class!

Comment: Most importantly I think, `MyClass::function()` doesn't make sense, since `MyClass` is not an actual class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I agree, however I chose another angle of attack to try to make the OP understand why it would be non-sensical rather than just asserting it.

Comment: And it's a good argument. +1. But I think the confusion between a class and a template class should be tackled as early as possible.

Comment: The only reason I want to put function() in MyClass is that it is _conceptually_ related to MyClass. In your example, function() does something which should depend on the typename.

Comment: @marcelnijman: that is what namespace are for: grouping related classes and functions together. If it is so closely related, then declare it in the same header to make it clear. If it is just related, then put the two headers in the same folder and have both live in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of a `template` as a `class`. It's just a skeleton on which classes are built.

`MyClass::function()` doesn't have any meaning, since `MyClass` is not an actual class unless you specialize it.

`MyClass<int>::function();` and `MyClass<char>::function();` might not depend on the template parameter, they might behave the same, but they are not the same function.

Let's take a look at the binary:

```
    MyClass<int>::function();
00D617CE  call        MyClass<int>::function (0D611C2h) 
    MyClass<char>::function();
00D617D3  call        MyClass<char>::function (0D611C7h)
```

For this, I provided an empty definition for `function`, so it definitely doesn't depend on the template parameter. As you can see, the two functions are different.

That's because there are two classes there generated by the compiler - `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<char>`.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a function definition which is typename independent, yet is added to every specialization?